# TestCafe: Unable to click onlclick action menu items

Tags: testing, onclick, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Unable to click onclick action menu items having javascript actions...

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-cyan active" href="#" onclick="javascript:__fnLoadScreen('Bodm/Layout?mode=CUD');" title="User Master">
  <i class="mdi-action-view-carousel"></i>User Master
</a>
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Would you please clarify what TestCafe version you are using? Is it an open source or commercial version? Are you recording an action using the Test Recorder or writing your own click handler? What exactly happens when you are trying to perform the click action?

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` tag must be defined without `javascript:` because it is already parsed as JavaScript.

```
< a class="waves-effect waves-cyan active" href="#" onclick="__fnLoadScreen('Bodm/Layout?mode=CUD');" title="User Master">< i class="mdi-action-view-carousel">< /i>User Master< /a>
```

Comment: Manually its working fine.. i.e. link is opening with javascript.. Since its standard application URL, i want to know how to click link with javascript in onclick using Testcafe..